# javascript print error when calling missing object property

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I would like to write a proxy object to automatically print errors when calling some property in original object which is not found.

```
const proxyObjectFn = () => {
  const _obj = Object.assign({}, originalObject);

  const get = (key) => {
    const value = _obj[key];
    if (value === undefined) {
      console.error(`${key} not found`);
    }
    return value;
  };

  return {
    get,
  };
};

const proxyObject = proxyObjectFn();

export default proxyObject;

// caller
proxyObject.get('someProperty')
```

This works, but is there any elegant way so that I can call through `proxyObject.someProperty` instead of `proxyObject.get('someProperty')`?

**Update**

Let me make it more specific. Actually I am writing a translation object.

Original object may be from json, like `{ "HELLO_KEY": "Hello World" }`. I am to call like `{ label: _t.SOME_I18N_KEY }` in UI display code, assuming `_t` is the proxy object above. I can print the warning to tell me there is missing translation.

Comment: An issue here is just because the value is undefined, doesn't mean the key doesn't exist. You could simply check `Object.hasOwnProperty(key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object:

```js
const handler = {
  get: (obj, prop) => {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) console.error(`${prop} not found`);
    return obj[prop];
  }
};

const _t = new Proxy({ "HELLO_KEY": "Hello World" }, handler);

console.log(_t.HELLO_KEY);
console.log(_t.SOME_NONEXISTENT_KEY);
```